# Hide a div using GwtQuery

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery

This is my code to hide a given DIV using GwtQuery:

```
$("#historySection").hide();
```

However, it does not hide at all.

This is the actual HTML div:

```
    <div id="historySection" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom pad10">
        <div data-field="history">
        </div>  
    </div>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your div is present in the DOM when you run the GQuery code ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. Could you put a breakpoint in your code, just after the hide() method is called? At that point, check the state of the historySection div in the DOM.